# Getting list of names of documents in a collection Google Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get the names of all the documents inside a collection. I'm able to get the data, but I can't seem to find the value of the name stored anywhere.

```
let docRef = db.collection("selections").document("0").collection(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
docRef.getDocuments { (docs, error) in
    for d in docs!.documents {
        print(d.data())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why I couldn't figure this our earlier.

```
let docRef = db.collection("selections").document("0").collection(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
docRef.getDocuments { (docs, error) in
    for d in docs!.documents {
        print(d.documentID)
    }
}
```